# Is systemd-timesyncd.service accessible via a dbus api?

Tags: dbus, systemd-timesyncd

I have to read the status of systemd-timesyncd.service whether to see whetther it has synchronized with the ntp . The System clock synchronized flag is not helpful since it does not show appropriate information

Answer (score 0):

There is a DBUS. See the [developer documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated/). They have this as an example:

```
$ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.timedate1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/timedate1
node /org/freedesktop/timedate1 {
  interface org.freedesktop.timedate1 {
    methods:
      SetTime(in  x usec_utc,
              in  b relative,
              in  b user_interaction);
      SetTimezone(in  s timezone,
                  in  b user_interaction);
      SetLocalRTC(in  b local_rtc,
                  in  b fix_system,
                  in  b user_interaction);
      SetNTP(in  b use_ntp,
             in  b user_interaction);
    signals:
    properties:
      readonly s Timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';
      readonly b LocalRTC = false;
      readonly b NTP = true;
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties {
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable {
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer {
  };
};
```

That is to "set" through dbus; not to "get".

> I have to read the status of `systemd-timesyncd.service` whether to see whether it has synchronized with the ntp

Is a whole different question though. As with most (if not all?) systemd services: they use the underlying procedure to do something. `systemd-timesyncd` uses `ntp` so your question is ... not correct. From the man page:

> `systemd-timesyncd` will look for files with a `.list` extension in `ntp-units.d/` directories. Each file is parsed as a list of unit names, one per line. Empty lines and lines with comments ("#") are ignored. Files are read from `/usr/lib/systemd/ntp-units.d/` and the corresponding directories under `/etc/`, `/run/`, `/usr/local/lib/`. Files in /etc/ override files with the same name in `/run/`, `/usr/local/lib/`, and `/usr/lib/`. Files in /run/ override files with the same name under `/usr/`. Packages should install their configuration files in `/usr/lib/` (distribution packages) or `/usr/local/lib/` (local installs).

---

What you want is possible with the

```
timedatectl
```

command.

> timedatectl may be used to show the current status of time synchronization services, for example [systemd-timesyncd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-timesyncd.service.html#).
>
> **status**     Show current settings of the system clock and RTC, including whether network time synchronization is active. If no command is specified, this is the implied default.
>
> **show**  Show the same information as status, but in machine readable form. This command is intended to be used whenever computer-parsable output is required. Use status if you are looking for formatted human-readable output.

Comment: timedatectl does show the synchronization status , but it only reads the kernel flag. Even if the ntp server is stopped, it still shows that the client is synchronized with the server. But on systemctl status systemd-timesyncd it correctly shows if the client has been synchronized or has timed out waiting for the connection. I want to know if this status is accessible via dbus?